# How do I merge multiple text file content uniquely in Python?

Tags: python

I have folder with many text files some of files has the same exact content to other. How can I merge just the unique content and ignore the duplicates?
I do not remove duplicate lines. My files as the following:

Text file1:

```
Line1
Line1
Line3
```

Text file2:

```
Line1
Line1
Line3
```

Text file3:

```
text1
Line2
text3
```

The result:

```
Line1
Line1
Line3
text1
Line2
text3
```

I tried this but this only combine all of them into one file:

```
import glob
txt_files = glob.glob('*.log')
with open('merged_files.txt','w') as merged_files:
    for f in txt_files:
        for line in open(f,'r'):
            merged_files.write(line)
```

How can I read all the files and write only unique content in single text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each log file, calculate the checksum and see if you already copied an identical file by checking whether the checksum is in the `checksums` set. If you didn't, add the checksum to the set and copy the file, otherwise move on to the next file.

```
import glob 
import hashlib

def get_sha1(file):
    checksum = hashlib.sha1()
    for chunk in iter(lambda: file.read(4096), b""):
        checksum.update(chunk)
    return checksum.hexdigest()

def already_copied(file, checksums):
    checksum = get_sha1(file)
    if checksum not in checksums:
        checksums.add(checksum)
        return False
    return True

checksums = set()
with open("merged_files.txt", "wb") as merged:
    for file in glob.glob("*.log"):
        with open(file, "rb") as file:
            if already_copied(file, checksums):
                continue
            file.seek(0) # Return to the beginning of the file.
            for line in file:
                merged.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
import glob

unique_set = set()
txt_files = glob.glob('*.log')
for f in txt_files:
    for line in open(f,'r'):    
        unique_set.add(line)

with open('merged_files.txt','w') as merged_files:
    for line in unique_set:
        merged_files.write(line)
```

But as @kawadhiya21 mentioned, if you have files far larger than computer's RAM size, you might need to use TRIE data structure.

Answer (score 0):

We need to more about your files. If the files are small, open each file, put each line in an array, make them unique and write them.

Or you can put each line in a [`set`](http://www.learnpython.org/en/Sets) and at the end get value and write them in a file (`set` has unique values only and rejects duplicate without raising exception).

But if you have files in GBs ie far more than computer's RAM size, you might need to use TRIE data structure.

Comment: I have thousands of text files their size about KBs. As I said I do not want to remove duplicate line in the file itself. I just want to ignore Text file2 because it has same content of Text file1 and only writeText file1 in this case.